# Rails Active Records using maximum and minimum simultaneously

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Below both the query work fines

```
Event.joins(:visit).where(:page_id => 3).group(:visit_id).minimum('events.time')

Event.joins(:visit).where(:page_id => 3).group(:visit_id).maximum('events.time')
```

I want to do find the diff `maximum('events.time') - minimum('events.time')` and group by `visit id`

For this I am writing below query

```
Event.joins(:visit).where(:page_id => 3).group(:visit_id).(maximum('events.time') - minimum('events.time'))
```

I am getting error, `(undefined method maximum for main:Object)`

can anyone help me out for this active records query

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're trying to call `maximum` and `minimum` as though they were helper or instance methods. You have to call them on an instance of an `ActiveRecord` object. In your case I'm guessing that you have `class Event < ActiveRecord::Base` at the top of your model file.

Even if you change your code to use the `ActiveRecord` methods, you still have malformed Ruby code at `(:visit_id).(maximum`. So if the calculation performs and you get a date your code would look like this:
`Event.joins(:visit).where(:page_id => 3).group(:visit_id).(SomeTimeStamp)`, which will throw a different error.

You'll have to rework your query either way, but the important thing to note is that you can't call `minimum` or `maximum` as helper methods.